# Having trouble with a C++ Square Class. Member function implementation and declaration

Tags: c++, class

My last question was closed after 2 minutes. I am simply asking for help with the member functions. I should have member functions checking the following:

1. whether the square is external to another;
2. whether the square contains another square;
3. whether the square is contained into another square;
4. whether the square is tangent externally to another square (that is,
   whether their borders are in contact but, except those border
   points, they are external to each other);
5. whether the square is tangent internally to another square (that is,
   they have points on the borders in common but, except those border
   points, one square is contained into the other one);
6. whether the border of the square intersects the border of another
   square.

my private members are: double x,y;

Should i have the public member functions then, using both x and y to compute the perimeter and area?

This is what i have so far:
the header file

```
#include  <iostream>
#include  <cmath>
class Square
{
int x, y;
int  size;

public:
Square(int x, int y, int size) : x(x), y(y), size(size) { }
~Square() {};
bool isExternal(const Square& rhs);
bool contains(const Square& otherSquare);
bool iscontained(const Square& otherSquare);

bool borderintersect (const Square& otherSquare);
bool bordertangent (const Square& otherSquare);
}
```

The implementation

```
#include "Square.h"


bool Square::isExternal(const Square& rhs) const {
    return (((x < rhs.x) || ((x + size) > (rhs.x + rhs.size)) &&  ((y < rhs.y) || ((y + size) > (rhs.y + rhs.size)) 
};
bool Square::contains(const Square& otherSquare)const {
};
bool Square::iscontained(const Square& otherSquare)const {
};

bool borderintersect(const Square& othersquare)
{
// If this square's bottom is greater than the other square's top
if ((this->y - (this->size / 2)) > (othersquare->y + (othersquare->size / 2)))
{
    return (false);
}
// the reverse
if ((this->y + (this->size / 2)) < (othersquare->y - (othersquare->size / 2)))
{
    return (false);
}
// If this square's left is greater than the other square's right
if ((this->x - (this->size / 2)) > (othersquare->x + (othersquare->size / 2)))
{
    return (false);
}

if ((this->x + (this->size / 2)) < (othersquare->x - (othersquare->size / 2)))
{
    return (false);
}
return (true);

bool Square::bordertangent (const Square& otherSquare)const {
};
```

The test program

```
#include "Square.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

int main() {

```
Square sq1(0, 0, 10);
Square sq2(1, 1, 10);

    if(sq1.isExternal(sq2)) {
    cout<<"Square 1 is external to square 2"<<endl;
}

if(sq1.contains(sq2){
    cout<<"Square 1 contains square 2"<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

Should i include this in the header file in order to get both the x and y of the coordinate and the size?

```
double  getX( )  const {  return x;  }
double  getY( )  const {  return y;  }
double  getSize( )  const {  return size;  }
```

Comment: What do `x` and `y` signify, exactly ?

Comment: I see no need for such functions (`perimeter()` and `area()`). They aren't among, nor required by, your listed requirements. And if you have them, I see no reason for them to be public. Does that answer your question?

Comment: You're not asking for help, you're asking to get your job done.
"please, write my homework" is not a valid question, at least not here.

Comment: i'm not asking you to write my homework. Part of the assignment is to calculate perimeter and area. Those are simple. What i'm having trouble with is checking whether a square is inside another square etc. This means i have to include coordinates, no?

Comment: Presumably since x,y are almost certainly some x,y co-ordinate for some part of the square you are modelling - You'll need a length at least to be able to do any more.

Comment: Or at least 2 x/y (or topleft /rightbottom pairs) combinations to be able to calculate width, area, perimeter. And at least some sort of coordinate system that enables you to check overlapping squares etc.

Comment: should i have 4 separate coordinates? then computing the distance between two of them will give the length?

Comment: What exactly is the assignment for? Math or CS?

Comment: Why do you now have `len` and `wid` ? If it's a square then it only needs one dimension.

Comment: Oh seriously - get some graph paper and cut out some squares - it is the physical manifestation of what you are trying to do - it should help you to model it on the computer then

Comment: Is this okay for the coordinate system? Square ( ): x(0.0), y(0.0), z(0.0), w(0.0)

Comment: small square, but it will do..

Comment: It depends on what you mean by `x`, `y`, `z` and `w` - just naming these variables doesn't tell us anything - you have to define what they *mean*.

Comment: The assignment is for CS. would int Area () {return side*2}

Comment: The 0.0 is the default constructor. It will create a square of these dimensions if none are specified by the user

Comment: Get a piece of paper. Draw coordinate system. Draw sqare1, with x,y,len and wid, draw square2. TIP: a square can be represented in 2 ways: as one corner and dimensions (x,y,len,wid) or as 2 opposite corners (x1,y1,x2,y2). For humans the first is easier to understand. To make comparisons of 2 squares, the latter is more convenient.

Comment: Would two opposite corners be easier than one corner and the length?

Comment: Once you have one, you can determine the other.

Comment: You can combine the isExternal, contains and contained since these are related (when a square is external, it is not contained) and when sq1 is containing sq2, sq2 is also contained by sq1.

Comment: you mean as 1 member function? how will the user check one of them separately?

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you're tripping up on where to start with implementing the class so I'll give you some guidance there. All of your questions deal with checking the relative positions of two squares in some coordinate space. To answer them, you will need to know two things about each square:

- Position (`x`, `y` coordinates (often a corner of the square))
- Size (`size`)

Assuming you definitely mean square, then the width and height are equal, so you only need one variable to store the size. If you can actually have rectangles, then you'll need `width` and `height`. These will need to be members of your `Square` class because each `Square` should have its own position and size. You *do not* need to store the coordinates of each corner of your square because you can work them out from the position and size - storing data that you can work out from data you already have is known as *redundancy* and is generally something you want to avoid. Here is how that would look in two different coordinate systems (one where `y` goes down and the other where `y` goes up):

```
 x-->
y                size
|   (x,y).___________________
v        |                   |
         |                   |
         |                   |
         |                   |
    size |                   |
         |                   |
         |                   |
         |                   |
         |___________________| (x+size, y+size)
```

---

```
          ___________________ (x+size, y+size)
         |                   |
         |                   |
         |                   |
         |                   |
    size |                   |
         |                   |
         |                   |
^        |                   |
|   (x,y).___________________|
y                size
  x-->
```

As an alternative, you could store *two* positions which are two opposite corners of your square. However, if you really are dealing with *squares*, not rectangles, you will need to manually enforce the invariant that the points must be the same distance away from each other along both axes. Rectangles would not have this invariant so this would be more applicable for them, but then operations such as translation become more complicated (you would now have to move two points rather than just one).

You will not need `perimeter` or `area` member functions. None of the questions require you to know either of these things. All of the questions can be answered by doing simple comparison between the positions and sizes of the two squares.

Whether you have them be private or not is a design issue. By making them private, you can control access to them through the `Square`'s interface. You could then provide public member functions so that you can check for answers to some of your questions, such as `bool Square::contains(const Square& otherSquare)` which you would call like `square.contains(otherSquare)`. Here's the beginnings of a possible class definition:

```
class Square
{
 private:
  int x, y, size;
 public:
  Square(int x, int y, int size) : x(x), y(y), size(size) { }
  bool contains(const Square& other)
  {
    // Do comparisons between x, y, size and other.x, other.y, other.size
  }
  // ...
};
```

Alternatively, you could have the functions at namespace scope (not members of `Square`) and either make them friends of `Square` or make the position and size members of `Square` public. For such a simple example, this will not be a problem.

---

> Should I include this in the header file in order to get both the x and y of the coordinate and the size?
>
> ```
> double  getX( )  const {  return x;  }
> double  getY( )  const {  return y;  }
> double  getSize( )  const {  return size;  }
> ```

These kinds of functions are commonly known as *getters*. They provide access to private member variables of a class. In your case, you do not need to provide these getters because the functions you are writing are member functions of `Square`. The member functions of `Square` have access to the private members of any other `Square`, so you don't need to get access through these getters.

However, if you wanted some *other* class to access the `x`, `y`, and `size` values for a given `Square`, then you would need to provide getters (or make the members public).

Comment: I think it would be easier to start with a point (an x and a y coordinate) and the length of the side. The square will then move "length" to the right and then length downwards, then length left, then length upwards?

Comment: @KristyAloumary From my experience, it is most common to store one corner (often the top or bottom left) and then the edges extend in one direction away from that. If you were to do as you said, the position would be the centre of the square and the length of an edge of the square would be `2*length`.

Comment: @KristyAloumary I've added an ASCII diagram that might help.

Comment: It does. Thank you very much. How would i differentiate between the top right and bottom right points. the top right is (x+size,y). the bottom right is (x+size and what?)

Comment: Top right is `(x+size,y)`, bottom right is `(x+size, y+size)`. Or for a rectangle `(x+width, y+height)`.

Comment: Shouldn't the bottom right y coordinate be less than the one we started with?

Comment: @KristyAloumary It depends which direction your coordinate axes go. In the example I have given, my `y` axis increases downwards. If your `y` axis goes upwards (like on a graph in mathematics), then you should probably store the bottom left corner instead. I'll show it in the diagram.

Comment: Can you please comment on the member functions? I am having trouble with number 4

Comment: @KristyAloumary I understand that you're new to the site. Welcome! Your best course of action right now is to try to implement the functions. When you've done your very best and it still doesn't work, ask a new question instead of updating this one. In that new question post all of the code you've written, what you expect the result to be and what's actually happening. Then I or somebody else will help you there. I will respond to your question about `getXXX()` functions in my answer here.

Comment: Okay, I will try and do that now. Also, when checking if a square is tangent or not, should i just check whether the two coordinates of that square are = to the any of the other squares 2 coordinates?

Comment: @KristyAloumary Exactly! You'll need to check if any two pairs of points are equal (top edge, left edge, right edge, bottom edge). But yes, you  have the right idea!

Comment: @KristyAloumary Also, if my answer (or anybody else's) helped you, please say thanks by accepting it (the green tick on the left)! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Start with something like this, and go from there

```
class Square
{
    double m_x, m_y;
    double m_length;

    public:
    Square(double x, double y, double length) : m_x(x), m_y(y), m_length(length) {}
    ~Square() {};

    bool isExternal(const Square& rhs);
}

--- implementation
bool Square::isExternal(const Square& rhs) 
{
    bool retval = true;
    // do some calculations ..
    return retval;
}


--- main

int main(void)
{
    Square sq1(0, 0, 10);
    Square sq1(1, 1, 10);

    if(sq1.isExternal(sq2) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Just avoid leading `_` because they're reserved for the implementation in many cases.

Comment: may i ask what the underscores are?

Comment: What significance does the underscore have?

Comment: So you can see whether a variable is a member variable. It's a variable naming convention.

Comment: Is what i have so far okay?

Comment: It's ok, make the naming a bit more consistent. You shouldn't need the getters, since you are making all calculations inside the class, thus the values can remain in there (ie not available outside).

Comment: Okay, that helps alot! Are the functions declared correctly in the implentation? thanks again.

Comment: Keep the declarations in the header file the same as the implementation. The constness (the trailing const in the implementation) must be the same, otherwise it will not compile.

Comment: Do you mean the last const? bool Square::contains(const Square& otherSquare)const {
}; Also, do I need the Square:: if i included the Square.h file?

Comment: Yes, Do you have a compiler? If you try to compile this, it will give you some errors, learn from these errors.

Comment: Yes, I am using Visual Studio 2010. I am getting an error "declaration is incompatible with "Sqaure.h" the names of the member functions are underlined.

Comment: Create a project, insert the files as you have them here, press F5 and see what happens. This will teach you more than me commenting, at least on code compilation. The error probably have to do with the const keyword, try keeping the declaration and implementation the same. The declaration in the header file is a sort of promise to all code using this class. It promises that the called function looks like this. The code itself is implemented in the implementation file. Since you made the promise about how the method looks like, you must keep your promise at the implementation.

Comment: bool isExternal(const Square& rhs) {
 if ( Square (a, b, c)!=Square (d,e,f) )}  I think this is wrong, do I need to overload the operator != in the header file?

Comment: You are being too hard on yourself, you first have to learn to walk before you learn to run. Overloading operators can be done here, but that would become too complex. Why not something like if((sq1.x < sq2.q || sq1.x + sq1.size > sq2.x+sq1.size) && (sq1.y < sq2.y || sq1.y+sq1.size > sq2.y + sq2.size)). Try cutting 2 squares and lie over each other as @sftrabbit suggested

Comment: where would sq1.y and sq1.q etc be defined?

Comment: eeh, when you are in your isExternal method you declared above, sq1 would be this.x (or just x) etc and sq2 would be rhs.x. in Contains, the sq2 would be otherSquare.x. You figure out the rest ;)

Comment: I will change what i have now in the question. Can you please help with one of the member functions? I should be able to do the rest once I have completed one successfully.

Comment: bool Square::isExternal(const Square& rhs) const {
    return (((x < rhs.x) || ((x + size) > (rhs.x + rhs.size)) &&  ((y < rhs.y) || ((y + size) > (rhs.y + rhs.size)) 
};